# Regular Expression to find values that don't start with a particular character sequence

Tags: javascript, regex

How to write a regular expression for something that does NOT start with a given **word**

Let's suppose I have the following list

- January
- February
- June
- July
- October

I want a regular expression that returns all but June and July because they they start with **Ju**

I wrote something like this **^[^ju]** but this return any starting with **J** or **U**
I need something that starts with **Ju**

Comment: is your answer general or language specific? there are many regexp engines with different capabilities

Comment: @user385411: Why did’t you say you’re using jQuery in the first place? That makes using regular expressions obsolete as JavaScript is more powerful than regular expressions.

Answer (score 12):

Try this regular expression:

```
^([^j].*|j($|[^u].*))
```

This matches strings that either do not start with `j`, or if they start with `j` there is not a `u` at the second position.

If you can use [look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you can also use this:

```
^(?!ju).*
```

Comment: no, still not there.
Actually, all what I want is the negation of ^Ju

Comment: @user385411: Well, it works for me (assuming a flag to use case insensitive matching).

Comment: Because you did not explain why his regular expression did not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to use regular expressions for complement matches. It works, but it is usually either really inefficient or engine-specific. Use a regex and combine it with the `not` operator instead.

Comment: what would be the best thing to do then.
I have a list and I want to hide all elements that does not start with 'Ju'
I am using JQuery

Comment: I have to find then the negation of match in JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Below regex will also work for words starting with ju,

```
^[j][u].*
```